# What is the better integration way between jBPM5 and EJB services?

Tags: ejb-3.0, business-process-management

I spend last week learning about jBPM 5.3 and how to integrate to my JEE6 web app to execute a workflow with human task. My web app its a standard 3-tier web app (JSF + EJB3 + Hibernate) and i think I can invoke jbpm core services from ejb and ejb services from jBPM ProcessEngine, but I want to know what is the better way to do the integration? Is it advisable to enter a new integration layer? How can a WorkItem get access to EJB services (JNDI only?)?. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You can do a jNDI lookup inside the workitem handler. You can do whatever you want inside the workItemHandler implementation.

Cheers